# Зачем нужен второй SRC?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'League Gothic';
  src: url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embeddedopentype'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Нельзя ли в этом примере использовать один SRC, т.е. так

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'League Gothic';
  src: url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embeddedopentype'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/League_Gothic-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Можно. Пишите, как хотите :)

Comment: @Yuri понял. Спасибо. Разбираю по книге "Девид Макфарланд - Новая большая книга CSS". Встретил такой фрагмент кода и появился вопрос такой.

Comment: Тут кому как удобно. Обычно так пишут, что бы в первой указать основную ссылку на шрифт, а потом уже второстепенные

Comment: @Yuri вот как. Понял. А разве format не для этого? По нему браузер поймет подходит для него этот шрифт или нет, если да, то скачает, если нет, то не скачает. Или я не правильно рассуждаю?

Comment: Оно будет воспринимать поочерёдно. Если первый не воспринимается, то он попробует подключиться к следующему и так пока все не проверит. `format`, насколько я знаю, нужен, что бы показать браузеру, какой тип имеет шрифт

Answer (score 2):

Судя по комментарию [здесь](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/), это может понадобиться для IE9 с его Compatibility Mode, но подробностей найти не удалось. Вообще, к слову, так-то для подключения шрифтов лучше использовать [что-нибудь вроде этого](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), тут сразу и все нужные опции (вплоть до сокращения числа символов для оптимизации), и корректно работающие стили на выходе.